# Как подменить ссылку на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Не могу найти готовый скрипт который выполняет следующую функцию:
Человек нажимает кнопку "Скачать", начинается загрузка файла **паралельно с этим** его переадресоовает на рекламную ссылку, наприм. yandex.ru.

Нашел скрипт:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "https://yandex.ru"
  }
}
```

Работет не как нужно(

Comment: Фу делать такое...

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл способ:

```
<button id="open_all">Клик</button>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('open_all').onclick = f_open_all;

function f_open_all() {
window.open("ссылка1");
window.open("ссылка2");
window.open("ссылка3");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Не получится. Для начала у пользователя покажется всплывающее окно о том, что что-то хочет открыться в новом окне и пользователь должен будет подтвердить открытие